# Wrong serializers used on aggregate

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am working of a kafka-streams application in which I process log events. In this case I want to aggregate WorkflowInput types into a Workflow type. I am having issues getting the aggregate working.

```
final KStream<String, WorkflowInput> filteredStream = someStream;
final KTable<String, Workflow> aggregatedWorkflows = filteredStream
    .peek((k, v) -> {
        if (!(v instanceof WorkflowInput)) {
            throw new AssertionError("Type not expected");
        }
    })
    .groupByKey()
    .<Workflow>aggregate(Workflow::new, (k, input, workflow) -> workflow.updateFrom(input),
            Materialized.<String, Workflow, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("worflow-cache")
                .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                .withValueSerde(Serdes.serdeFrom(new JsonSerializer<Workflow>(), new JsonDeserializer<Workflow>(Workflow.class)));
```

I get the following exception:Caused by: `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: A serializer (key: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer) is not compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String / value type: workflowauditstreamer.WorkflowInput).`

Two things to notice:
 * The value serializer is a StringSerializer, while I configured something different using `withValueSerde`.
 * The actual value type is `WorkflowInput` while I expect `Workflow` since that is my aggregated value type.

I am new to kafka-streams so I might be missing something obvious, but I cannot figure it out. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not sure how `someStream` is built. Can it be, that the error originate in `groupByKey()` and you need to provide a correct `Serde` for the value there?

Comment: Sorry it took me tthis long to get back to you. I edited the snippet with the assertion that holds. Furthermore if I remove the `aggregate` and keep the `groupByKey` I do not get the serialization exception.

Comment: You still don't show how you get `someStream`... Do you read it via `StreamsBuilder#stream(...)` ? Can you show the code? I still assume, you need to pass `Produced.with()` into `groupByKey()` to set the value serde for `WorkflowInput` type.

Comment: Again sorry for the delay (I recently became father). You were right... I needed to pass a `Serialized.with(keySerde, valueSerde)` to the `groupByKey`. I mistakenly assumed that since the serdes were previously selected, they would propagate in the stream... Thanks for the help. If you add your comment as an answer I will (swiftly) accept it.

Comment: No worries. And congratulations!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you overwrite default `Serde` from the config, it's in operator in-place overwrite. It's not propagated downstream (Kafka 2.0 -- there is WIP to improve this).

Thus, you will need to pass in the `Serde`s you use in `someStream = builder.stream(...)` into `.groupByKey(Serialized.with(...))`, too.