# How to use custom serializers with KTable in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am facing some errors during serialization of `KStream` to `KTable` when I introduced the `groupBy` to my `KStream`. As I understood, once you have an `aggregate` or `reduce` on a `KStream`, Kafka tries to transform it to a `KTable` due to necessary shuffle and because of this Kafka has to serialize the records again. So, my original `KStream` was just mapping the records from `JSON` to `AVRO` like this, and it is working fine.

```
    @StreamListener("notification-input-channel")
    @SendTo("notification-output-avro-channel")
    public KStream<String, NotificationAvro> process(KStream<String, PosInvoice> input) {
        log.info("received PosInvoice JSON: {}", input);
        KStream<String, NotificationAvro> notificationAvroKStream = input
                .filter((k, v) -> v.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(PRIME))
                .mapValues(v -> recordBuilder.getNotificationAvro(v));
        notificationAvroKStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Notification avro - key: %s, value: %s", k, v)));
        return notificationAvroKStream;
    }
```

then I introduced the `groupByKey` and `reduce` and I realized that it transforms to a `KTable` and hence it needed `Serdes` on the `application.yaml` file. But unfortunately I cannot configure the default `Serdes` because I have other types of serialization. Hence I decided to serialize on the `KTable` topology. I am trying to implement this solution [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54062509/2096986).

The part of the code that I try to materialize with my custom serdes is not working properly (`Materialized.with(CustomSerdes.String(), CustomSerdes.NotificationAvro())`). First, I don't think I need `KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("mystore");`, but without this it also does not work and I cannot find a materialized that is not `KeyValueBytes...` where I can define my serdes `CustomSerdes.String(), CustomSerdes.NotificationAvro()`.

According to the answer that I mentioned on the link, they also use a `final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();`. But since I am computing it using `spring-kafka` I don't have this option, or if I have I don't know how to use.

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@EnableBinding(PosListenerJsonAvroBinding.class)
public class NotificationJsonAvroProcessorService {
    @Autowired
    RecordBuilder recordBuilder;

    @StreamListener("notification-input-channel")
    @SendTo("notification-output-avro-channel")
    public KStream<String, NotificationAvro> process(KStream<String, PosInvoice> input) {
        log.info("received PosInvoice JSON: {}", input);
        KStream<String, NotificationAvro> notificationAvroKStream = input
                .filter((k, v) -> v.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(PRIME))
                .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getCustomerCardNo(), recordBuilder.getNotificationAvro(v)));
        notificationAvroKStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Notification avro - key: %s, value: %s", k, v)));

        // *********************************************
        // IS THERE A KeyValueStoreSupplier THAT I CAN PASS ALSO MY SERDES INSTEAD OF Bytes?
        // KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("mystore");
        KTable<String, NotificationAvro> convertedTable = notificationAvroKStream
                .toTable(
                        // *********************************************
                        // HOW TO MATERIALIZE KTABLE VALUES WITH SERDES ?
                        Materialized
                                // .as(storeSupplier) // this is not necessary
                                .with(CustomSerdes.String(), CustomSerdes.NotificationAvro())
                        // *********************************************
                )
                .groupBy((cardNo, notificationAvro) -> KeyValue.pair(cardNo, notificationAvro))
                .reduce(
                        (aggValue, newValue) -> {
                            newValue.setTotalLoyaltyPoints(newValue.getEarnedLoyaltyPoints() + aggValue.getTotalLoyaltyPoints());
                            return newValue;
                        },
                        (aggValue, oldValue) -> oldValue
                );
        KStream<String, NotificationAvro> notificationAggAvroKStream = convertedTable.toStream();
        notificationAggAvroKStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Notification agg avro - key: %s, value: %s", k, v)));

        return notificationAggAvroKStream;
    }
}
```

the custom serdes:

```
@Service
public class CustomSerdes extends Serdes {
    private static final String schema_registry_url = "http://localhost:8081";
    private final static Map<String, String> serdeConfig = Collections
            .singletonMap("schema.registry.url", schema_registry_url);
    public static Serde<NotificationAvro> NotificationAvro() {
        final Serde<NotificationAvro> notificationAvroSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
        notificationAvroSerde.configure(serdeConfig, false);
        return notificationAvroSerde;
    }
}
```

and the error:

> Exception in thread
> "NotificationJsonAvroProcessorService-process-applicationId-3e262d96-19ca-438d-a2b8-9d3c2e9bb4ab-StreamThread-1"
> org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: ClassCastException
> while producing data to topic
> NotificationJsonAvroProcessorService-process-applicationId-KTABLE-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000010-repartition.
> A serializer (key:
> org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer / value:
> org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.ChangedSerializer) is not
> compatible to the actual key or value type (key type: java.lang.String
> / value type: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.internals.Change).
> Change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes
> via method parameters (for example if using the DSL, `#to(String topic, Produced<K, V> produced)` with
> `Produced.keySerde(WindowedSerdes.timeWindowedSerdeFrom(String.class))`).
> ...
> ...
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class
> com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.model.NotificationAvro
> cannot be cast to class java.lang.String
> (com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.model.NotificationAvro is
> in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.String is in module
> java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I solved through reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52372015/2096986), which is using the `.groupByKey(...)` and `Serialized.with(...)` that are deprecated. I am using the `Grouped.with(CustomSerdes.String(), CustomSerdes.NotificationAvro())`.

```
KStream<String, NotificationAvro> notificationAvroKStream = input
     .filter((k, v) -> v.getCustomerType().equalsIgnoreCase(PRIME))
     .map((k, v) -> new KeyValue<>(v.getCustomerCardNo(), recordBuilder.getNotificationAvro(v)))
     .groupByKey(Grouped.with(CustomSerdes.String(), CustomSerdes.NotificationAvro()))
     .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> {
          newValue.setTotalLoyaltyPoints(newValue.getEarnedLoyaltyPoints() + aggValue.getTotalLoyaltyPoints());
          return newValue;
     })
     .toStream();
notificationAvroKStream.foreach((k, v) -> log.info(String.format("Notification avro agg - key: %s, value: %s", k, v)));
return notificationAvroKStream;
```